# rosbag info C++ API

Tags: ros, rosbag, ros-comm

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there any way to recover the number of messages of a given topic from a .bag file using the C++ API?

I know the Python API does, which is used in `rosbag info <bag>` (I think, by means of the `_get_yaml_info` Bag class method), but I'd like to know whether we have the same feature in the C++ API or not?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/28766/rosbag-info-c++-api/) by [Enrique](https://answers.ros.org/users/244/enrique/) on ROS Answers with karma: 834 on 2012-02-28

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you try the rosbag::View::size method? As I understand it, it should return the number of messages. Maybe std::distance(view.begin(), view.end()) could also work, but not sure about that.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-02-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Enrique](https://answers.ros.org/users/244/enrique/) on 2012-02-29**:
I mean to obtain the number of messages without reading them, like rosbag info does (as I mention in my question). Currently, I read all messages using C++ API, and I convert them to some ASCII files I need, but only at the end I know the number of messages, and I need it at the very beginning.

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-02-29**:
Sorry. My fault. I updated my answer.

**Comment by [Enrique](https://answers.ros.org/users/244/enrique/) on 2012-02-29**:
rosbag::View::size() works! It uses std::distance in its implementation, btw. Thanks a lot!

**Comment by [YancenBOB](https://answers.ros.org/users/44257/yancenbob/) on 2019-08-14**:
@Enrique
Hi. I met almost the same question or need to get the number of messages in a rosbag. I used the function  view.size() but it showed the size_cache (uint32) and it was 68435, not the value of the messages number. How could I make it works? Thank you